Is using dynamic window size over frequency, break the Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle?
As Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle says, we cannot observe the high resolution frequency and high resolution time at same time. There is trade-off where we focus observe high resolution frequency with resulting of low resolution time and vice versa.
Sorry for the naive question, but it simply clear to me by intuition that we can perform windowed Fourier Transform a.k.a Short-time Fourier Transform with dynamic window size.
The algorithm is simple like this:
INPUT: signal -> 1D array (list of amplitudes)
OUTPUT: spectrograms -> 3D array (window size axis, frequency axis, time axis)

FOR every window_size FROM epsilon TO length_of_signal
  current_spectrogram := compute_stft(signal, window_size)
  spectrograms.append(current_spectrogram)

We would get high resolution frequency and high resolution time information aren't we?

People ask about this sorta thing periodically.

Heisenberg’s uncertainty principle is related to fundamental particles, not to digital signals. If you’re not doing Quantum Mechanics, then Heisenberg’s doesn’t apply to you.

@CrisLuengo $ \Delta E \Delta t\ge \frac{h}{4\pi}\Leftrightarrow \frac{\Delta E \Delta t}{h} \ge \frac{1}{4\pi} \Leftrightarrow \Delta f \Delta t\ge \frac{1}{4\pi} $

@CrisLuengo Don't forget, the digital signal is sampled based on real world. And real world is working on Quantum Mechanics. It's true that what digital computer sees the signal is just list of amplitude (vector) and its sample rate (scalar) as reference to represent how many nodes in 1 second that has been sampled in real world.

Look. the longer the piece of signal we take, the more precisely we can determine its frequency, so if we want higher temporal resolution in the frequency measurement, then the frequency measured is less precise. But this has nothing to do with the Plank constant, it's not Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle. It might sound similar, but it's not related in any way. You might want to refer to this as the Gabor Limit or simply as the Uncertainty Principle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Uncertainty_principle
